# Ruler doesn't start from mouse & scale on object & pose mode is different

Tags: armature, world, scale

The ruler's start point appears at certain distance from the mouse

[image: Ruler problem]

As for the issue on scale, I've set my scene to metric. I'm using armature to drive keyshapes so on object mode the armature's location is 1cm = 1cm while I was in pose mode, moving the bones, 1cm = 10cm.

Anyone knows what's wrong? This is the 3rd time I'm using this method and it worked fine in other previous projects

I've tried resetting the user preference but it didn't work.

Let me know if there's anything else I need to show or clarify.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Ruler /Protractor

Ctrl+Left Mouse Button (will snap the start point) and Hold ctrl and drag

[image]

It snap to the edges

[image]

Comment: It works on other files however this specific file, Idk why even with left click it doesn't snap but keeps starting in this general area away from the center & 3dCursor

Comment: @ThDreamer attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Okay I found the problem for the ruler however it'd be nice If I can find out why my pose and object mode scale is different. 
Done. File is uploaded above 

Problem of the ruler, I have two 3D views, I create the ruler in Screen 1 but drew it in Sceen 2 thus the effect as above.